# "Company's engineer" - What does it mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is *company's engineer* in this context? Does it refer to the stakeholders?

> If aircraft maker Boeing is trying to win a contract from United Airlines, it will emphasize different qualities when it talks to **the company's engineers**, purchasing people, chief financial officer, and CEO — since each United participant will consider different matters during the purchase process.
>
> [[*Market your Way to Growth: 8 Ways to Win,*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xneLB2aewlUC&pg=PA50&lpg=PA5) Kotler & Kotler, pub Wiley 2012]

Comment: It means the engineers the company employs, as opposed to its "purchasing people", CFO and CEO.

Answer (score 2):

It is talking about the engineers employed by United Airlines, who shall have a say in the contract granting process.

Comment: That is correct. It is listing a number of different people who will be involved in the process of making this decision.  They're specifically referring to aviation engineers, the people who build and maintain the airplanes of United Airlines.

Answer (score 1):

"the company's Engineers" most likely means literal mechanical/aviation engineers employed by the company.

I can see your confusion, but since an airline employs a number of such engineers, many of whom oversee a number of technical regulations, this is probably who they mean.  Not "the people who engineered the company".